# Diffeomorphism: Unit Ball vs. Euclidean Space

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

In my differential geometry class we are being asked to prove that the open unit ball

$B^n$ = { $x$ $\in$ $\mathbb{R}$$^n$ such that |$x$| < $1$}

is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$$^n$

I am having a hard time with this as I am brand new not only to differential geometry, but also topology.

I know that I need to construct a smooth, differentiable bijection between the two with a differentiable inverse, but beyond that, I am unsure of where to start. Some guidance in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try doing it for $n=1$ first.

Comment: For a text, I'd recommend Lee's *Introduction to Topological Manifolds* starts out with an accessible introduction to the relevant topology with a view toward manifolds, and is a readable, compact introduction to the titular subject. (Full disclosure: I know Lee personally.)

Comment: Ah, thanks! I've heard that his Introduction to Smooth Manifolds book is also great. By any chance would you recommend that I read one before the other, or does it matter?

Comment: My books are written to be read in the order _Topological Manifolds_ -> _Smooth Manifolds_ -> _Riemannian Manifolds_. You'll get a lot more out of them in that order. Happy reading!

Comment: Wow, I wasn't expecting to hear back from the author himself! Thanks for the tip, it's very much appreciated.

Comment: @cappuccino: I agree with the others: Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds!

Comment: @JackLee: What I really missed was a motivation for why considering regular balls in the construction of a partition of unity (--> compactness!). Apart from this your book is just great!!! Especially, the enlightening comments all over they are really helpful. Thanks for your contribution to literature! :)

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $\phi \colon [0,1) \to [0, \infty)$ a diffeomorphism with inverse $\psi$. Some possible choices: $t \mapsto \frac{t}{1-t}$, $t \mapsto \tan (\frac{\pi}{2}\cdot t)$.

The map 
$$x \mapsto \phi(||x||) \cdot \frac{x}{||x||}$$

is a diffeomorphism from $B^n$ to $ \mathbb{R}^n$ with inverse 
$$y \mapsto \psi(||y||) \cdot \frac{y}{||y||}$$

$\bf{Added:}$  It turns out that the choice of the diffeomorphism from $[0,1)$ to $[0,\infty)$ matters a lot, since $x \mapsto ||x||$ is not smooth at $0$. This was brought to my attention by @Freeze_S and I thank him a lot! One can check that the map obtained for $\phi(t) = \frac{t}{1-t}$ is only $C^1$ at $0$... However, we can use the map so kindly suggested by @Jesus RS: ( big thanks! ) $\phi(t) = \frac{t}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}$ with inverse 
$\psi(s) = \frac{s}{\sqrt{1+s^2}}$ and it will work just fine. The diffeomorphisms are, as written by @Jesus RS:
$$x \mapsto \frac{x}{\sqrt{1-||x||^2}} \\ 
y \mapsto \frac{y}{\sqrt{1+||y||^2}}$$

In fact, as long as $\phi(t)$ is an odd function of $t$ things will work OK. So, another example is

$$x \mapsto \frac{\tan (\frac{\pi}{2} \cdot ||x|| )}{||x||} \cdot x $$

Comment: One must also take (as you surely have in mind) that $\phi$ is increasing, so that $\lim_{t \to 0^+} \phi(t) = 0$. Also, one must check that the map $x \mapsto \phi(||x||) \cdot \frac{x}{||x||}$ (well, pedantically, its extension by $0$ to continuity) is smooth at $0$. Is this true for the candidates $\phi$ you suggest?

Comment: @Travis: Oh, let's just take the half closed intervals, thanks for the observation! I see the issue with the smoothness at $0$, perhaps harmless since in fact $\frac{\phi(||x||)}{||x||}$ is smooth at $0 \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @orangeskid: No, not harmless! Consider for example: $\phi(|x|)=\frac{1}{1-|x|}$ But the problem is not that it doesn't tend to zero or that it's not increasing the problem is that it is not smooth at zero. That's why for example you have to consider a more sophisticated construction, as is done in Lee's SM.

Comment: @Freeze_S Thank you. Yes, there is an issue with the smoothness at $0$. Let me see if anything can be salvaged. Note that the map from the ball to the full space is $x \mapsto \frac{1}{1-||x||} \cdot x$

Comment: The homeomorphism from the ball to the full space yes: $\varphi(x):=\frac{x}{1-\|x\|}$ Now, I just remember that there's a diffeomorphism from any open submanifod to the whole manifold. But one needs to check that precisely.

Comment: @Freeze_S: Any open star domain is diffeomoprhic to the full space. That may be a little more difficult to prove.

Comment: @orangeskid: You mean diffeomorpic in the usual sense or in the manifold sense. Note that I don't specify its shape but allow any open submanifold.

Comment: @Freeze_S: That would be in the usual sense. But I am not sure about the statement for an open submanifold.

Comment: @orangeskid: Ah yes the notions agree then. Ah and my statement was wrong: The open annulus cannot be even homeomorphic to the euclidean space since it is not simply connected.

Comment: @Freeze_S: Yes, you are correct. Also check out http://mathoverflow.net/questions/114528/are-homeomorphic-open-subsets-of-mathbbrn-also-diffeomorphic where they mention that there could exists open subsets of an $\mathbb{R}^n$ that are homeomorphic but not diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$  -- this can happen for some $n$'s. Fascinating!

Answer (score 8):

Or you can try $f(x)=x/\sqrt{1-|x|^2}$ for $x\in B^n$.

Comment: Thank you, this is the one. And I used it to salvage my answer.

Answer (score 3):

**Standard Approach**

Consider the identification:
$$\Phi:\mathbb{B}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n:\Phi(x):=\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-\|x\|_E^2}}$$
Its inverse is given explicitely by:
$$\Psi:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{B}^n:\Psi(y):=\frac{y}{\sqrt{1+\|y\|_E^2}}$$
The argument of the roots never vanish:
$$1-\|x\|_E^2\neq0\quad1+\|y\|_E^2\neq0$$
So they're both differentiable.

**Alternative Approach**

Consider the identification:
$$\Phi:\mathbb{B}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n:\Phi(x):=\frac{x}{1-\|x\|_E^2}$$
By the inverse function theorem:
$$\mathcal{N}d\Phi(x)\equiv(0)\implies\mathrm{d}\Psi(y)=\mathrm{d}\Phi(\Psi(y))\in\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^n)$$
But this holds globally as the identification is a bijection.

**Problematic Approach**

Consider the identification:
$$\Phi:\mathbb{B}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n:\Phi(x):=\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-\|x\|_\infty^2}}$$
This is most likely not differentiable.

Comment: I am sorry, I am confused that how can we ensure the norm is smooth?

Answer (score 2):

Not every smooth function induces a smooth map:
$$\Phi:\mathbb{B}\to\mathbb{R}:\quad\varphi(|x|):=\frac{1}{1-|x|}$$
Just have a careful look at its diagram:

[image: Diffeomorphic Ball]

*(Note that it is not even differentiable at zero!)*

The problem is that the norm is not smooth in general:
$$\|\cdot\|:V\to[0,\infty)$$

One can master this almost only by patching a bump on top:
$$\varphi(r):=e^{-\frac{1}{r^2}}\cdot\frac{1}{1-r}$$

For a mere diffeomorphism still the whole story highly depends on the chosen norm!

Answer (score -3):

As to the book recommendations I suggest the following:

**(i)** A course in Differential Geometry (W. Klingenberg)

**(ii)** Elementary Differential Geometry (A. Pressley)

**(iii)** Differential-Geometrie und Minimal-Flächen (J. Jost) (in german but it's a wonderful book).

Some more advanced books dealing with differential geometry in the context of differentiable manifolds I'd suggest:

**(v)** Differential Geometry: Manifolds, Curves and Surfaces (M. Berger, B. Gostiaux)

**(vii)** A Comprehensive Introduction to Differential Geometry (M. Spivak) (all the volumes)

I hope it helps.

As to your question about the diffeomorphism between the open unit ball and $\mathbb R^n$ the idea is defining a function which will stretch the open ball in all directions.