# Given a chart $(U,\phi)$ find a chart $(V,\psi)$ such that $(U,\phi)$ and $(V,\psi)$ are $C^\infty$-compatible and $\psi(V)=\mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

On page 4 of the book "Differential Topology" (written by Amiya Mukherjee) the following is written:

> [...] observe that the charts $(U,\phi)$ and $(U,\alpha\circ \phi )$,
>   where $\alpha:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^n$ is a **diffeomorphism**,
>   are always **compatible**. In particular, taking $\alpha$ to be the
>   translation which sends $\phi(p)$ to $0$, we can always suppose that
>   every point $p\in M$ admits a coordinate chart $(U,\phi)$ such that
>   $\phi(p)=0$. We may also suppose that $\phi(U)$ is a convex set, or
>   the whole of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

In that book the word "diffeomorphism" means "$C^\infty$-diffeomorphism" and two charts $(U,\phi)$, $(V,\psi)$ are said to be compatible if $\psi \circ \phi ^{-1}:\phi(U\cap V)\to\psi(U\cap V)$ is a $C^\infty$-diffeomorphism.

My question is about the end of the above quote: *"We may also suppose that $\phi(U)$ is a convex set, or the whole of $\mathbb{R}^n$"*.

---

**Question:** Given a chart $(U,\phi)$ how can I prove that exists a chart $(V,\psi)$ such that $(U,\phi)$ and $(V,\psi)$ are $C^\infty$-compatible and $\psi(V)=\mathbb{R}^n$?

---

I tried to use the questions below to answer my question but I couldn't.

- [Equivalent Definitions of a Topological Manifold: Are Open Sets in $R^n$ homeomorphic to $R^n$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1213847/equivalent-definitions-of-a-topological-manifold-are-open-sets-in-rn-homeomo)
- [Diffeomorphism: Unit Ball vs. Euclidean Space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1025308/diffeomorphism-unit-ball-vs-euclidean-space)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is that we need only to find a subset of $U$ such that the image under chart map $\phi$ is an open ball $B_r(0)$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$. After this, we can blow up the ball to $\mathbb{R}^n$ by a diffeomorphism. Suppose we have a chart $(U,\phi)$ with a point $p \in U$ having $\phi(p)=0 \in \phi(U)\subset \mathbb{R}^n$.

- Let $V=\phi^{-1}(B_r(0))$ for some $r>0$ and $\psi :=\phi|_V$. Then $(V,\psi)$ is $C^{\infty}$-compatible with $(U,\phi)$ since it is just restriction of the larger chart.
- Choose your favorite [diffeomorphism](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1025308/diffeomorphism-unit-ball-vs-euclidean-space) $\alpha : B_r(0) \to \mathbb{R}^n$, we have new chart $(V,\alpha \circ \psi)$ with $(\alpha \circ \psi)(V) = \mathbb{R}^n$ and $C^{\infty}$-compatible with $(V,\psi)$ as you can verify it by yourself.
- Therefore $(V,\alpha \circ \psi)$ $C^{\infty}$-compatible with $(U,\phi)$ with $\psi(V)= \mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: One question: is there a $C^\infty$-diffeomorphism  $\alpha:B_r(0)\to\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: @rfloc  The accepted answer here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1025308/diffeomorphism-unit-ball-vs-euclidean-space provide a diffeomorphism from unit ball to $\mathbb{R}^n$. You can tweak it easily by scaling to any non-unit radius ball.